# Sharing multiple variables between threads in Python

Tags: python, queue, python-multithreading

I want to share multiple variables across multiple threads in Python.

I know `queue` is considered as the best way to share a variable between threads. Following this, I will be needing a separate `queue` for each variable. Is there any better approach than this to share multiple variables across multiple threads ?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Combine the variables into a single object/namedtuple, and share that.

Comment: In that case, the thread has to load the values in the beginning and the values used may be old. I am using a looping thread.

Comment: I am afraid I don't follow. If you want the values to be live, share references; if you want the values to be snapshots, share copies.

Comment: I want the latest values in every thread.  Can you send me a small code implementing the shared references part?